# How to jump on specific Page usinig Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to get data for Product which are search by user in python.I am able to get data from any Urls but depending upon search Jump on that page and Get data Using beautifulsoup.

I Try this for get data :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib2

 url="http://amazon.in"
 con=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()    
 soup=BeautifulSoup(con)
 print soup.prettify()
```

But if user want price of IPhone 5s then it will jump to that product page and get data.

How I get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do a get request passing the correct params:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

params = {"url":"search-alias=aps","field-keywords":"iphone 5"}
url = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2"


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params).content)
ul = soup.select_one("#s-results-list-atf")
```

ul will be contain all the search results you see on the page. If we run the code and find the h2 tags inside each anchor, you can see the item name/description as you see on the page.

```
In [6]: ul = soup.select_one("#s-results-list-atf")

In [7]: for h2 in ul.select("li a h2"):
   ...:         print(h2.text)
   ...:     
Apple iPhone 5s (Space Grey, 16GB)
Apple iPhone 5s (Silver, 16GB)
Supra Lightning 8 Pin To Micro Usb Charge Sync Data Connector Adapter Iphone 5 Ipad 4
OnePlus 3 (Graphite, 64GB)
Apple iPhone 5 (Black-Slate, 16GB)
ROCK 695029068729 Royce Series Shockproof Dual Layer Back Case Cover for Apple iPhone 5 5S,(Grey)
Apple iPhone 5c (White, 8GB)
iSAVE Soft Silicone Grid Design Back Case Cover For iPhone 5/5s (BLACK)
iPaky AT15312 360 Protective Body Case with Tempered Glass for Apple iPhone SE 5 5S,(Black)
Aeoss 9Pcs Open Pry Screwdriver Repair Tool Kit Set For iPhone 6 Plus 5 5s 5c 4 iPod.
2 IN 1 Tempered Glass for Iphone 5 5s 5c Explosion Proof Tempered Glass (FRONT AND BACK)
Itab iphone5sclearsoftgelly Imported Transparent Clear Silicone Jelly Soft Case Back Cover For Apple Iphone 5 5S
Shivam Earphones EarPods Handsfree Headphones for Apple iPhone 4/4s/5/5s/6/6+ (White)
USB Power Adapter Wall Charger&Data Cable for iPhone 5/5S/5C/6
Generic Ios 7 Compatible Data Sync Charging Cable For Apple Iphone 5 5S 6 - White
Tempered Glass Screen Protector Scratch Guard for Apple Iphone 5 5G 5s
```

Comment: ul = soup.select_one("#s-results-list-atf")
    for h2 in ul.select("li a h2"):
        print(h2.text) is not working and its show list object has no select method somthing like this

Comment: You are not using my code if that is the error you see, *select* is not *select_one* so you have mixed them up somewhere

Comment: how whould i get that search url
like amazon = http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2
 if i want for flipkart Then how i ll get it??